# Throw Error on Google Cloud Shell but not on Studio Code

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[A screenshot of the full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8e5i.png)

Whenever I run npm start on the cloud shell I run into this error, the strange thing is, the web app which this code belongs to is already deployed and fully functional, and I have never gotten a error for it on VS code, however now that I'm trying to create a staging/development version of the same web app on Google Cloud Platform, i keep running into this error when doing a npm run.

Thank you so much for the help in advance!

```
      throw new Error('apiKey value must be defined!')
      ^

Error: apiKey value must be defined!
    at new Mailgun (/home/nuveqsb/hello-world/test-staging/api/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/mailgun.js:16:13)
    at create (/home/nuveqsb/hello-world/test-staging/api/node_modules/mailgun-js/lib/mailgun.js:239:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nuveqsb/hello-world/test-staging/api/utils/onesignal.js:27:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nuveqsb/hello-world/test-staging/api/utils/notify.js:4:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set up environmental variables/configurational variables?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I thought I could just carry on using the whatever was configured previously, apologies for my ignorance, I am rather new to all of this.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.